# Benefit of declaring class as pointer?

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I know there had been a discussion similar to this in the past but answers appear to be outdated in my opinion.  Most say that the differences are the following:

1. **Scope** - since on the old questions ask with examples of these objects declared inside the method instead of as a member of the class.
2. **Safety from memory leak** - old questions use raw pointers rather than smart pointers

Given my example below, class `Dog` is a member of class `Animal`. And is using smart pointers. So the scope and memory leak are now out of the picture.

So that said.. What are the benefits of declaring a class with a pointer rather than a normal object? As basic as my example goes - without considering polymorphism, etc.

Given these examples:

```
//Declare as normal object
class Dog
{
public:
    void bark()
    {
        std::cout << "bark!" << std::endl;
    }
    void walk()
    {
        std::cout << "walk!" << std::endl;        
    }
};

class Animal
{
public:
    Dog dog;
};

int main()
{
    auto animal = std::make_unique<Animal>();
    animal->dog.bark();
    animal->dog.walk();
}
```

And..

```
//Declare as pointer to class
class Dog
{
public:
    void bark()
    {
        std::cout << "bark!" << std::endl;
    }
    void walk()
    {
        std::cout << "walk!" << std::endl;        
    }
};

class Animal
{
public:
    Animal()
    {
        dog = std::make_unique<Dog>();    
    }
    std::unique_ptr<Dog> dog;
};

int main()
{
    auto animal = std::make_unique<Animal>();
    animal->dog->bark();
    animal->dog->walk();
}
```

Comment: It really depends on how your classes are meant to be used. Will they be extended (other methods/logic/members)? As your code stands, there is no point in declaring a pointer there.

Comment: If `Dog` is never derived from then all is fine, but if there are `Bulldog` and `Poodle` derived from `Dog` and both can be assigned to `Animal::dog` then you have to have a pointer.

Comment: With your current example there is only a performance overhead in using a pointer.

Comment: Your example is not helpful in exploring benefits or otherwise of pointers,  The main benefit of using a `Dog *` or a `std::unique_ptr<Dog>` is the ability to use polymorphism IF `Dog` is a polymorphic base (which it isn't in your example).   It is also possible to dynamically create an array of `Dog` with the size determined at run time (but that array cannot contain instances of classes derived from `Dog`).    In your case (`Dog` not polymorphic) neither of those benefits can be achieved, and all you have achieved is additional overhead of dynamically creating and destroying objects.

Comment: I know it's just an example, but it's a strange model to say "every Animal has a Dog".

Comment: @aschepler - there are animals that will eat dogs.   It that case, the "contains" relationship is literal.

Comment: Thanks everyone. As I mentioned in my post: 
"As basic as my example goes - without considering polymorphism, etc." So I guess in cases like this, a normal object should be used. That clarifies it for me.